# EF Core 3 Linq could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I tried to build a query in ef core 3.0 that gets the full process from the db server

```
 IEnumerable<int> stIds = stateIds;
  var rtables = await db.Order.
                Join(db.OrderDetail, order => order.OrderId, orderdetail => orderdetail.OrderId, (order, orderdetail) => new { order, orderdetail }).
                Where(x => x.order.SellerId == sellerId && stIds.Contains(x.orderdetail.OrderStateId)&&x.order.RtableId != null)
                .GroupBy(x =>             
                x.order.RtableId               
                )
                .Select(x => new RtableState { RtableId = x.Key ?? 0, OrderStateId = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.orderdetail.OrderStateId).Select(x => x.orderdetail.OrderStateId).FirstOrDefault() }).ToListAsync();
```

I get this error:

{
    "Message": "Processing of the LINQ expression       'AsQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType52>(OrderByDescending<<>f__AnonymousType52, int>(\r\n    source: NavigationTreeExpression\r\n        Value: default(IGrouping, <>f__AnonymousType52>)\r\n        Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e), \r\n    keySelector: (x) => x.orderdetail.OrderStateId))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.",
  "Inner": ""
    }

I know the query is too complex for EF Core 3.0, but is this a bug or should it not work?

My solution is to split the request.

```
IEnumerable<int> stIds = stateIds;
            var rtableStatesServer = await db.Order.
                Join(db.OrderDetail, order => order.OrderId, orderdetail => orderdetail.OrderId, (order, orderdetail) => new { order, orderdetail }).
                Where(x => x.order.SellerId == sellerId && stIds.Contains(x.orderdetail.OrderStateId) && x.order.RtableId != null)
                .GroupBy(x => new RtableState
                {
                    RtableId =

                x.order.RtableId ?? 0,
                    OrderStateId = x.orderdetail.OrderStateId
                })
                .Select(x => new RtableState { RtableId = x.Key.RtableId, OrderStateId = x.Key.OrderStateId }).ToListAsync();


            var rtableStates = rtableStatesServer.GroupBy(r => r.RtableId,
                        (key, value) => new RtableState
                        {
                            RtableId = key,
                            OrderStateId = value.OrderByDescending(x=>x.OrderStateId).Select(x => x.OrderStateId).FirstOrDefault()
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated in the exception message, the problem is caused by the expression

```
x.OrderByDescending(y => y.orderdetail.OrderStateId)
    .Select(y => y.orderdetail.OrderStateId)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

where `x` is `IGrouping<,>` produced by `GroupBy` operator.

> This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

I would consider it a limitation, which might never be fixed because `GroupBy` result containing expressions other than key and aggregate expressions have no natural SQL equivalent.

The general solution is to avoid `GroupBy` where possible and use alternative constructs with correlated subqueries. But this particular query has simple natural solution because the expression

```
set.OrderByDescending(item => item.Property).Select(item => itm.Property).FirstOfDefault()
```

can be expressed with

```
set.Max(item => item.Property)
```

which is a standard (thus supported aggregate).

Replace the aforementioned problematic expression with

```
x.Max(y => y.orderdetail.OrderStateId)
```

and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, you are right i used x.Max() and it work !  I guest thought to complicated.